# How to download google slide as video using google api?

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-slides-api, google-slides

I am using google developer api as raw request with php. My requirement is to play the google slide which will comes with all the animation and transition duration, for this google slide's `embeddedlink` is not the option for me because it shows the task baar. So i am searching for any other way like google slide to video download.

I am looking for a way where i can download the google slide as a video with the help of google api. I don't know that does google provide any api for that or not but i researched alot through the google api docs and other site but i failed to get any way, can any one knows the way or any other way to come out from this.

Please help me.

Comment: When it downloads files using Google APIs, users often use Drive API. Using "about.get" of Drive API as a field of "exportFormats", you can retrieve the formats which can be directly exported from Google Drive. The response also includes the formats of Slides. At current stage, Slides can export as "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation", "application/pdf", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation" and "text/plain". The format as a video is not included. Is this useful for you? [Reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/about/get).

Comment: yes i have also found the export formats as pdf,text,pptx but video format is not there that means google does not export slide as video ?

Comment: Unfortunately, at the current stage of Google APIs, Slides cannot be exported as a video yet. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: it's fine thanks @Tanaike